# how to do a "fill with color"(from mspaint) with a picturebox?

Tags: .net

I did a little research and I didn't find a way, anyone know?

c# or vb.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[In the end I used this code](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=556493)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a flood fill algorithm? Check this for example: [Flood Fill Algorithms in C# and GDI+](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/floodfillincsharp.aspx)